# Como implementar un swiperefreshlayout con recyclerview y cardview

Tags: android

tengo implementado un parserXML con Listview  y cardview, pero no se como implementar el swiperefreshlayout para refrescar el contenido.

NO se donde colocar el codigo para que vuelva a leer el xml desde mi servidor, he buscado tutoriales pero no logro encontrar uno que me ayude con esto.

Gracias por sus comentarios, en mi clase que carga las noticias lo tengo asi.

```
      public class fnoticias extends Fragment implements  adaptadorNoticia.OnItemClickListener{}

El codigo que ejecuta el parser con el adapter esta asi.

 public class TareaDescargaXml extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<noticia>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // show the progress bar
            spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
        @Override
        protected List<noticia> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                return parsearXmlDeUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null; // null si hay error de red
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                return null; // null si hay error de parsing XML
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<noticia> result) {
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE );
            // Actualizar contenido del proveedor de datos
            noticia.Ultimas_Noticias = result;
            // Actualizar la vista del adaptador
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

y mi layour lo tengo asi

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/reciclador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Espero me puedan guiar.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente agrega como contenedor de tu `ListView`, el **[SwipeRefreshLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html)**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Aquí puedes revisar la documentación:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html